# Need to get combinations of each

Tags: python, r, combinations

I have a problem to resolve. The problem consists of choosing the best combination of variables to include into the model.
To do so I thought to calculate combine the items in a list with the names of variables then include to the model and choose the combination which returns the least RMSE.
However, I have 70 variables and for combining all of them I will not have enough memory in PC.
Please let me know what else could be a valid solution. Cheers.\

Comment: Can you add some example code? what model is it? what language are you using (You've tagged 2)? etc

Comment: You could look up "stepwise regression" and "L1 regularization"/"lasso regression"

Comment: @Aurèle and then look up why these models are not great for variable selection.

Comment: @Aurèle Thank you so much. Would you mind to share with me a simple guide of how run correctly this models?

Comment: @EmiOB Hi! Thank you for your comment. To be honest I don't have any preference between Py/R. For me is important to know the methodology. The code that i have used for model is a simple lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4....Xj, data=df)

Comment: If you're using linear regression than variable selection can start with what data meets the assumptions of linear regression. However, if you'd like to find the variables that best represent the outcome, regardless of whether it's linear or not, you could use a random forest model with importance, i.e., `randomForest::randomForest(..., importance = T)` After creating the model, you can look at how 'important' each predictor is to the outcome. There are methods to look at the interaction, but you could just look at importance in general to start. *RF is particularly well-suited for wide data.